# What's the difference between @media screen and (max-width:770px) and @media screen and (max-width:770px + 30px)

Tags: css

I just got a project that I  am supposed to work on. In the CSS file of this project, I found the following code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 770px + 30px) {
    .rw-layout {
        margin: 10px;
    }
}
```

I tried to find out how it can affect the element `.rw-layout` but it is not working.

I tried to view in the developer tools of Firefox and no information as others:

[image]

So the question I am asking is that, what is the use of `@media screen and (max-width:770px + 30px)` in the project?

Comment: The difference is 30 px

Comment: You could also write 800px. Most probably the 770px + 30px is a result of a css precompiler like less, sass, scss...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's invalid CSS and won't work in many (if any) browsers.
If I had to guess how it happened, one possible scenario is perhaps he made a media query in a CSS preprocessor like Sass with variables - something like:

```
$tablet: 770px;
$pad: 30px;

@media screen and (max-width: $tablet + $pad) { }
```

But the variables ended up being transcluded instead of added up during compilation.

Either way, it's meaningless code the way it's currently written and will not execute - it doesn't mean `800px` or `770px`.